# Split Dos/windows text file into smaller multiple Unix text files?

Tags: batch-file

First of all i using WINDOWS OS and not Linux,all i want is to Split a big file from Dos/windows text file into smaller multiple Unix text files?All tools i tried,they spliting in to dos/windows format,always,and i want a tool, a command line,anything to split a big Unix txt file to smaller unix txt files or from dos/windows big txt file to smaller Unix txt files

Comment: Why not split the task? 
A program that splits the text file and
one which converts it from windows text to normal text?

An example of the first can be found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602869/batch-file-to-split-csv-file). It even splits on whole lines.

And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings point to using the `MORE` command in windows with some nice command switches.